# How to avoid poor flow in these sentences with "divorced his wife" and "divorced his ex-wife"?

Tags: time, flow

Consider the sentence

> He had been living in the city ever since he divorced his ex-wife.

and the alternative

> He had been living in the city ever since he divorced his wife.

Both have imperfect flow. With the first, a pedant might start thinking it was incorrect because if a woman is a man's ex-wife he can't technically divorce her, not even if he marries her again first because then she would be his wife again rather than his ex-wife. In the second, a reader who might not even be especially pedantic might need to backtrack because he might read the words "his wife" as if they applied to a state of affairs existing at the same time as what is expressed in the first clause, namely the man's residence in the city. Changing grammatical tense by writing "had divorced" rather than "divorced" doesn't get around the problem here.

What alternatives might avoid the time-frame difficulty?

Comment: Less clunky: "He had been living in the city since his divorce." Besides not confirming the marriage to be heterosexual (assume that a male divorces a wife), I omitted 'ever' too, because the 'had' confounds it.

Comment: *What* time-frame difficulty? The past perfect continuous phrase establishes a time context, and there is no doubt that the man divorced his wife prior to that.

Comment: The second is clear and idiomatic enough. "He quit his job" —of course it was only "his job" *until* he quit it. Things really get hairy when you separate the causal action from the relationship: "I was living in the city with my then-wife"...

Comment: I don't see how you can divorce an ex-wife unless after remarriage.

Comment: 'He had been living in the city ever since he divorced his then wife.' But the man on the Clapham omnibus could then say that this sounds both clunky and pedantic.

Comment: Another option: He had been living in the city ever since he divorced. / I see no pedantry. // Have you ever taken a look at English Language Learners?  Very helpful SE site!

Comment: While "divorced his wife" sounds more natural, I can't imagine anyone finding fault with "divorced his ex-wife" -- it clearly means "divorced the woman who is now his ex-wife". The worst thing about it is that it's redundant -- since he divorced her, she's obviously an ex-wife.